# Futuro do pretérito vs. Condicional (diferenças na formalização da gramática)

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, tempo-verbal, termos

Eu estava estudando a gramática de algumas línguas românicas e notei uma peculiaridade de como a gramática do português é formalizada, em especial o português brasileiro.

As línguas derivadas do latim têm sistemas de flexão verbal similares, apresentando algumas flexões em comum, como na palavra *"cantaría/cantaria"*, comum ao português, espanhol, galego, etc. Em todas as gramáticas e tabelas de conjugação de todas as línguas românicas que li, tal conjugação chama-se **condicional** (ou **tempo condicional**). E.g., no [castelhano](http://en.espagram.ru/conjugation-verb-cantar/), no [italiano](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cantare#Conjugation), no [romeno](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?T1=c%C3%A2nta&Submit=Go&D1=5&H1=105), no [francês](http://www.conjugation-fr.com/conjugate.php?verb=chanter&x=30&y=31) e no [português europeu](http://european-portuguese.info/conjugator/cantar).

Porém, nas gramáticas feitas para o português brasileiro, tal conjugação chama-se **futuro do pretérito** (enquanto que o tempo **futuro** passa a se chamar **futuro do presente**).

- Por que tal diferença existe na gramática do português brasileiro?
- Qual é a lógica por trás dos nomes "futuro do presente" e "futuro do pretérito"? (I.e., por que faz sentido atribuí-los às respectivas conjugações?)

Na minha opinião, é muito mais óbvio e intuitivo dizer que *"cantarei"* e "*cantaria*" estão no futuro e no condicional, respectivamente, do que em diferentes flexões do tempo futuro.

Comment: Em castelhano, denomina-se também «pospretérito» (é dizer, futuro do pretérito). No asturiano, pode ser quer condicional quer presente do modo potencial.

Comment: @hugo Maria diz hoje «amanhã farei X», em dois dias, eu poderia dizer «há dois dias, Maria disse-me que *faria* X ontem». O tempo da narração fica dois dias no passado, mas a ação (de fazer X) ocorre um dia depois, que obviamente está no futuro com respeito ao tempo de narração.

Comment: Ups, disse que era o presente do potencial no asturiano, que é errado, quis dizer o pretérito do potencial (o presente do potencial é o mesmo do futuro haha)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que pude verificar, esta conjugação também era chamada de **condicional** no Brasil. Porém, a sua denominação foi alterada em 28 de janeiro de 1959, pela [**Portaria nº 36 do Ministério da Educação e Cultura**](https://docs.ufpr.br/~borges/publicacoes/notaveis/NGB.pdf).

A Portaria baseou-se no trabalho feito por uma comissão de estudiosos (citados no link acima), que sugeriu várias mudanças, entre elas a alteração da denominação de **condicional** para **futuro do pretérito** - na página 4 do link acima, na seção **VI - Verbo**, item **c**:

> c) de tempo: presente; pretérito: imperfeito (simples e composto); perfeito (simples e composto); mais que perfeito (simples e composto); futuro do presente (simples e composto) e do pretérito
>   (simples e composto).
>   **Nota: A denominação futuro do pretérito (simples e composto) substitui a de condicional (simples e composto);**

Já [este artigo](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI6867,51045-Futuro+do+preterito) afirma que Portugal não participou da mudança, embora não mostre evidências do mesmo. Este mesmo artigo ainda sugere uma hipótese para as motivações de tal alteração:

> ... uma das hipóteses de sua ocorrência pode ter sido o fato de que a *condição*, nesse caso, não reside no tempo verbal sob análise, mas na estrutura sintática da outra oração como um todo, como é fácil verificar no seguinte exemplo: *"Eu **compraria** uma casa, **se tivesse dinheiro**"*.

Answer (score 2):

Em complemento à resposta de user1798, a lógica em que os nomes se baseiam consiste em diferenciar as ações que ocorrerão futuramente em relação a seus referenciais.

### Futuro do presente

O que acontecerá após agora; acontecerá depois, utilizando como referencial o presente.

> "Ele fará o dever de casa.". Neste exemplo, 'ele' fará depois, depois de agora, isto é, o presente.
>
> "Amanhã eu irei à praia.". Amanhã é posterior ao presente e ao passado, porém o presente tem prioridade, pois algo que ocorre posterior ao passado referenciado mas antes do presente seria futuro do pretérito.

### Futuro do Pretérito

O que acontecerá após o passado e antes do presente, algo que ocorreria em um tempo futuro àquele que estamos narrando ou referenciando; ou algo que iria se desenrolar se uma condição presente/passada fosse/tivesse sido diferente.

> "O garoto deparou-se com uma grande entrada, na qual ele entraria após perceber que ela o levaria a seu destino.". Após deparar-se com a entrada, o garoto entrou; tudo isso ocorreu no passado, porém a entrada do garoto foi depois da deparação.
>
> "Eu jogaria com ele se não estivesse chovendo.". Se água não estivesse caindo do céu agora, o jogo aconteceria.
>
> "Eu teria jogado com ele se não estivesse chovendo.". A oportunidade de jogar e a chuva naquele momento já passaram. Se água não estivesse caindo do céu no passado, o jogo teria acontecido nesse mesmo passado.