# Explicação das siglas ou codificação dos verbos na obra de Mattoso Câmara (representação acrográfica)

Tags: gramática, verbos

Eu queria que alguém fizesse a correspondência da ***representação acrográfica*** usada por Joaquim Mattoso Câmara Júnior (as siglas que representam o tempo, modo, aspecto dos verbos) à forma como modernamente são mostrados os verbos por exemplo no [priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/trazer) . (Por exemplo, o que corresponde a Imperativo positivo e negativo?)

As obras contemporâneas que se escrevem por referência à obra mattosiana usam esta codificação mas muitas vezes não contém um quadro que explique o que cada sigla/índice significa. Depois em prosa muitas vezes é referido "Grupo do perfeito" ou "Grupo do presente" sem que seja claro a que conjunto de modo-tempo-aspecto se referem esses grupos.

Por exemplo no resumo [deste artigo](https://www.e-publicacoes.uerj.br/index.php/cadernoseminal/article/view/32693/0) ou nesta tese: [Morfologia ornamental : as vogais temáticas do português brasileiro](https://acervodigital.ufpr.br/handle/1884/63255).

O seguinte foi a explicação das siglas (codificação) que encontrei do próprio autor

> ["Estrutura da Língua Portuguesa"](https://www.google.com/search?&q=estrutura+da+lingua+portuguesa+Joaquim+Mattoso+C%C3%A2mara+J%C3%BAnior), Joaquim Mattoso Câmara Jr. (1970). Cáp 53 pág 107.
>
> (...) no padrão geral dos verbos portugueses.
>
> Antes de fazê-lo, de acordo com a técnica descritiva iniciada
> por Pânini, adotemos uma representação acrográfica para os modos
> e tempos portugueses.:
>
> Indicativo: Id. Subjuntivo não-subordinado ou Imperativo: Sb<sub>1</sub>
> Subjuntivo subordinado, ou propriamente dito: Sb<sub>2</sub>. Infinitivo: If. Gerúndio: Gd. Particípio: Pa.
>
> Presente: Pr.. Pretérito Imperfeito: Pt<sub>1</sub>. Pretérito Perfeito: Pt<sub>2</sub>.  Pretérito Mais que Perfeito: Pt<sub>3</sub>. Futuro do Presente: Ft<sub>1</sub>.  Futuro do Pretérito: Ft<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: O pessoal brasileiro em especial devia gostar desta pergunta, muitas vezes dei por mim a ver serem usadas estas siglas sem explicação nem legenda. Achei um post valioso para ter no pt.se, agora se alguém procurar encontra logo isto.

Answer (score 1):

A correspondência entre as siglas usadas por Mattoso da Câmara e os tempos e modos verbais
-como hoje estamos habituados a vê-los organizados nas tabelas de conjugação verbal- é mostrado no quadro seguinte.

| Sigla | Conjugação |
| --- | --- |
| **Indicativo** |  |
| **IdPr** | Presente do Indicativo |
| **IdPt<sub>1</sub>** | Pretérito Imperfeito do Indicativo |
| **IdPt<sub>2</sub>** | Pretérito Perfeito do Indicativo |
| **IdPt<sub>3</sub>** | Pretérito Mais-que-Perfeito do Indicativo |
| **Ft<sub>1</sub>** | Futuro do Presente |
| **Ft<sub>2</sub>** | Futuro do Pretérito [(isto é o Condicional em Portugal)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4592) |
| **Subjuntivo** |  |
| **SbPr** | Presente do Subjuntivo |
| **SbPt** | Pretérito Imperfeito do Subjuntivo |
| **SbFt** | Futuro do Subjuntivo |
| **Imperativo** |  |
| **Sb<sub>1</sub>** | Infinitivo (positivo ou negativo?) |
| **Formas nominais** |  |
| **Ge** | Gerúndio |
| **Pa** | Particípio Passado |

É de mencionar que o [Futuro do Pretérito do Indicativo em Portugal é chamado Condicional](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4592). Por vezes é agrupado
com os outros tempos do Indicativo (como no [conjugacao.com.br](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-trazer/)) ou então é mostrado num grupo separado (como no [priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/trazer)). Nesta tabela optei por manter agrupado.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132370/discussion-on-answer-by-bad-coder-explicacao-das-siglas-ou-codificacao-dos-verbo).